# Linking ffmpeg code in microsoft visual studio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have compiled ffmpeg code on visual studio by linking all .lib files using this http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1309 link. while compliling the code i m getting error like 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'X11/Xlib.h': No such file or directory
1>  x11grab.c

I could not find x11 file in ffmpeg source code . please help to solve this error .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you **do not** specify the `--enable-x11grab` flag during configuration. (You may try to specify explicitly `./configure --disable-x11grab`)